# Why is Shadow Task not Finding Referenced DLL?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

A unit test project migrated from VS2010 still uses the auto-generated private property accessors.

After many hours of coding and testing a solution that includes a class library project, the unit test project for the class library project, and a web project, suddenly the error manifests.  The web project is executed under IIS Express.

> Error 24 Could not load file or assembly 'The.ClassLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. The.ClassLibrary.Tests

Facts

- The.ClassLibrary.Tests has a project reference to The.ClassLibrary.
- There were no other build errors (checked build output not just errors window)
- The DLL is physically present with a current timestamp in `bin\debug`
- I restarted IIS Express
- I restarted Visual Studio
- Cleaned / Rebuilt the solution

Answer (score 0):

**Option A**

*Work around the issue. It may happen again.*

In addition to the steps tried, it was also necessary to search for and delete *all* occurrences of The.ClassLibrary.Dll on the disk.  So, the full procedure is:

- Stop IIS Express
- Exit Visual Studio 2012
- Search for and delete *all* instances of the "missing" DLL.
- Start Visual Studio 2012

I hope this helps someone.

**Option B**

*Fix the issue properly*

Private accessors are depreciated in VS2012.  Instead, make *private* things that need to be visible to the unit test *internal* instead, and use the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute in `AssemblyInfo.cs` of the project being tested to allow the test project access to internal properties, methods and fields of the test subject.

*AssemblyInfo.cs* (of MyProject)

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyNs.MyProject.Tests")]
```